# Registration of web Application on google developer console

Tags: java, api, gmail, google-oauth

Here, are the steps of registration, I have doubts regarding step 3, 4, 5:

1. When you create your application, you register it using the Google Developers Console. Google then provides information you'll need later, such as a client ID and a client secret.
2. Activate the Google Calendar API in the Google Developers Console. (If the API isn't listed in the Developers Console, then skip this step.)
3. When your application needs access to user data, it asks Google for a particular scope of access.
4. Google displays a consent screen to the user, asking them to authorize your application to request some of their data.
5. If the user approves, then Google gives your application a short-lived access token.
6. Your application requests user data, attaching the access token to the request.
7. If Google determines that your request and the token are valid, it returns the requested data.

After the basic registration I got the client id, secret key and give the redirect uri. Details till now:

```
{
  "web": {
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "client_secret": "bnltOn4nljP-d4AwgWHleEuV",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "client_email": "588495213967-rhg8i6lmcc0eqq34fuk97lkj36agog3v@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    "redirect_uris": [
      "http://static.enggheads.in/gmail"
    ],
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/588495213967-rhg8i6lmcc0eqq34fuk97lkj36agog3v@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "588495213967-rhg8i6lmcc0eqq34fuk97lkj36agog3v.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "javascript_origins": [
      "https://static.enggheads.in"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have a button on click of it I have reached the verification page where it asks "Manage your contacts" i.e my scope as I want user contacts.

But I don't know from where and how to actually get the access token.

Comment: you should update your client's secret now it is published here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you agree to the requested scope "Manage your contacts" you'll be redirected to your application with a `code` as in `http://static.enggheads.in/gmail?code=<code>`. You can pickup the `code` value in your application and exchange it for an access token at Google's token endpoint. This is all described in Google's documentationn here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: I have tried it too..  I have that code also and just trying to exchange it for access token but i m getting:  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) on statement JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

Comment: Sir plz check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298827/google-contacts-v3-api-oauth-v2-in-java/16315679#16315679  I am using the code frm here the 1st ans.

Comment: Hans Z Sir please help me with this isssue.