# Contact v3 Compatibility issue

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

I am trying to fetch all user contacts from Gmail like LinkedIn etc using oauth2 for authentication and contact api for getting the contact. But there is some compatibility issue of jar files I am using *Google API Client 1.14.1 (beta) jar* and tried using *com.google.gdata-contacts-1.41.5.w1.jar* for contact service & contact feed but the code is not working and continuously giving Internal Server Error. How to resolve the issue? How will I know that particular jar files are compatible.

[I am using code from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298827/google-contacts-v3-api-oauth-v2-in-java/16315679)

The url for aouth authorization I have given on a button click:-
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=your_client_id_goes_here&redirect_uri=your_redirest_urls_goes_here&scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/&response_type=code

```
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    out.println("JACKSON :: "+jsonFactory);
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest authorizationTokenRequest = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(transport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, request.getParameter("code"), REDIRECT_URL);

    GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = authorizationTokenRequest.execute();

    out.println("OAuth2 Access Token: " + tokenResponse.getAccessToken());

    /*GoogleCredential gc = new GoogleCredential();
            gc.setAccessToken(tokenResponse.getAccessToken());
            out.println("gc :: "+gc);*/
    ContactsService contactsService = new ContactsService("Socioengg");
    //  Credential credential = exchangeCode(request.getParameter("code"));
    //contactsService.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
    out.println("-------------------------------Hellloo::"+contactsService );
    contactsService.setAuthSubToken(tokenResponse.getAccessToken());

    out.println("Succeeded :: "+contactsService);

    try {
        URL feedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/");

        Query myQuery = new Query(feedUrl);
        myQuery.setMaxResults(1000);

        ContactFeed resultFeed = contactsService.query(myQuery, ContactFeed.class);

        for (int i = 0; i < resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) {
            out.println(resultFeed.getEntries().get(i).getTitle().getPlainText() + "<br/>");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }}
```

Comment: You must add an example of what you had tried. Without it is difficult to help. See the help on how to ask question in Stackoverflow.

Comment: My code isn't working when contact service instance is been created

Comment: Any help Sir PhoneixS

Comment: Sorry, but I don't use oauth so I can't help you. But now that the question is better wrote I think that somebody will help you.

Comment: OAuth2 involves ask consent to the user (giving him/her a URL to click), and I cannot see this in your code.